# Sharp Architecture WCF

Tags: wcf

I have unusual problem that I can't figure out.

I have a sharp architecture project that I am developing, and using WCF services which I host using IIS ASP.NET.

When the services were hosted on my machine everything worked out fine. Now I have hosted the services on a different server and running the client from my machine. once I have done that the SaveOrUpdate() methods seems to be not working. No errors are being thrown out and it returns a successfull operation, but the data is not persisted to the db. The issue I can't figure out is why was this working when the services were hosted locall and now not working when they are hosted some where else.

Comment: Posting your config files and some code with your question might be helpful.

Comment: What is Sharp architecture? Edit: http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into a similar issue before, basically the transaction is never committed. try manually beginning and committing  your transactions.